# I can't boot to custom recovery directly

Tags: recovery-mode

Good day to everyone. I have a problem with my SKK Lynx (rebranded Ulefone be Pure) phone. I've installed a custom recovery on it (Philz Touch) via RashR. I am able to use it successfully but I have to use an app to boot directly to recovery like quick boot because when I try to boot to recovery via the power + vol down button, it goes to the stock recovery which is in Chinese characters.

I want to be able to booth to the custom recovery directly because I don't always have access to the quick boot. Can anyone help me? What do I have to do? Thank you very much.

P.S The steps I've taken are: 
try TWRP,CWM,and Philz which does the same thing
rename the recovery file in the data/etc folder to .bak

Comment: Sounds like the installed recovery is the stock recovery. So basically you would want to replace the stock recovery image with a custom one (TWRP/CWM). Are you sure that **you've flashed and installed the custom recovery and not just booted into it**? (like a fastboot boot recovery.img would do) I've never used Rashr but I believe it support both flashing and just booting up a custom recovery...

Comment: thank you for the fast reply! I believe I flashed it using the Rashr by choosing flash recovery from storage. The only other option is flash kernel from storage. Others are just reboot options.
here is a link of the instructions I followed, except that I used a recovery file from android cribs. (http://skkmobilelynxsupport.blogspot.com/2015/03/tut-have-cwm-custom-recovery-for-skk.html)

Comment: Mhm weird. Sounds like you've done exactly what every guide tells you to. So just a basic check? Can you confirm that you **are rooted**? Have you renamed the custom recoverys to "recovery.img" before flashing? [XDA-Guide for Custom Recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61808806&postcount=2)

Comment: Yes I did rename the file. I am sure I am rooted because I used an app and reboot app needs a rooted phone to work. By the way I rooted my phone with Kinguser app because the superuser doesn't seem to work on my phone. Also, I've just installed a new rom and the same thing happened.